# how to load views in a base html view in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I Need to load two html files  in a base html file .In other words I have base html file in which I have header and contend view .I need to load different HTML file in header and in contend view ..
Here is Base HTML file

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row page-header">
        <ui-view name="header"></ui-view>
    </div>

    <ui-view name="content"></ui-view>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <hr>
            <p class="text-center">Test Come</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this view

```
  <ui-view name="header"></ui-view>
```

in header I need to load header.html and   `<ui-view name="content"></ui-view>` in thisI need to load content.html
http://plnkr.co/edit/nMhlb0R1q3BhWBHEjCks?p=preview
Thanks

Comment: You are mixing <ng-view> with <ui view> which is not desired "https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#issue-problems-when-using-ng-view-alongside-ui-view" way to do either choose ng-view or ui-view for routing.

Comment: I change something http://plnkr.co/edit/nMhlb0R1q3BhWBHEjCks?p=preview

Comment: could you please change my plunker

Comment: You can use <div ng-include="'content.html'"></div> and <div ng-include="'header.html'"></div> if possible or you want to work with <ui-view>..??

Comment: @squiroid I am using ui-view http://plnkr.co/edit/nMhlb0R1q3BhWBHEjCks?p=preview ..Please check where I am doing wrong

Comment: any update ? may i am going correct

Comment: hey wait i m working....

Comment: "http://plnkr.co/edit/hm1yALKqkl4VvTaAb8nG?p=preview"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68628/discussion-between-squiroid-and-user944513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have just one ng-view.
You can change its content in several ways: ng-include, ng-switch or mapping different controllers and templates through the routeProvider.

UI-Router is a project that may help: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router One of it's features is Multiple Parallel Views

**EDIT**

Checkout this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qfyrvR5z04IXMvH1rKXq?p=preview)

There were some problem with your code

(1) inject $stateProvider instead of $routeProvider if you are uing ui-router

(2) use ui-view instead of ng-view

(3) you can have multiple view at same template level. If you tries to define ui-view inside ui-view and you create multiple ui-view in single state, it will not work.

(4) ui-view inside ui-view will create another state.

```
var app=angular.module("firstApp",['ui.router']);
var config = function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
   $stateProvider
    .state('base', {
      url: "/",
        views: {
        "content": { templateUrl: "contend.html" },
        "header": { templateUrl: "header.html" }
      }
    })
};
config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];

var loginCntrl=function($scope){

}
loginCntrl.$inject=['$scope']

app.config(config);
app.controller(loginCntrl);
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/nMhlb0R1q3BhWBHEjCks?p=preview I upload that could you please check my plunker

Comment: Could you please look on my plunker

Comment: i have edited my answer. Check http://plnkr.co/edit/qfyrvR5z04IXMvH1rKXq?p=preview also.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your state according to child states:

```
var config = function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
       $stateProvider
       .state('main', {
        url: '/',
        views: {

            // the main template will be placed here (relatively named)
            '': { templateUrl: 'base.html' },


            // the child views will be defined here (absolutely named)
            'content@main': { template: 'contend.html' },

            // for column two, we'll define a separate controller 
            'header@main': { 
                templateUrl: 'header.html',

            }
        }

    });
};
```

Comment: could you please send link